# Log4j2 configuration not found with Intellij and Kotlin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, log4j2

I built a fresh IntelliJ project with Gradle and the Kotlin DSL build script, only Kotlin (Java) and java version 10.0.2 as project SDK.

I added the dependencies for log4j into build.gradle.kts:

```
compile("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1")
compile("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1")
```

And I put a log4j2.yaml file into /src/main/resources with some configuration.

When I now run this test program:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val logger = LogManager.getLogger()!!

    logger.warn("Warn")
    logger.info("Info")
    logger.debug("Debug")
}
```

I do not get logging output but this message

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
```

*How do I get log4j2 to work?*

Here's what I've done so far:

- I checked that the log4j2 config is copied to the build directory and included in the classpath
- I successfully read the resource file via `classloader.getResource("log4j2.yaml");`
- I tried an xml config file instead

Comment: If I'm not mistaken [already solved a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572783/no-log4j2-configuration-file-found-using-default-configuration-logging-only-er).

Comment: Going through the answers of that thread: Cleaning does not help/is not applicable, putting the config in src/main/{java,kotlin} instad of src/main/resources does not help, but this helped, see answer in a minute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40421738/1216878 PS: Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, that these dependencies are not enough if you want to use YAML config files. Additionally these are required:

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.9.4")
```

After including these requirements into `build.gradle.kts`, logging worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

if any one is using maven. please add bellow dependancies to the project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
```