# After updating Spring Boot(1.5.20.RELEASE), getting error in AWS environment, but working fine in local

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j2

After updating to Spring Boot (1.5.20.RELEASE) - I'm getting the following error in my latest environment (in AWS) but in local it is working fine.

*ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.*

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ttt-rest-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.wdat.ttt</groupId>
        <artifactId>ttt-middleware-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-407.0.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <apache.cxf.version>3.1.11</apache.cxf.version>
        <swagger.version>2.1.8-M1</swagger.version>
        <jackson.version>2.4.4</jackson.version>
        <powermock.version>1.6.6</powermock.version>
        <easymock.version>3.4</easymock.version>
        <authz.version>2.8.1-56.0.0.14</authz.version>
        <mpropz.version>RELEASE</mpropz.version>
        <httpclient.version>RELEASE</httpclient.version>
        <start-class>com.wdat.ttt.Application</start-class>
        <lombok.version>1.16.8</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wdpr.ee</groupId>
            <artifactId>wdpr-loggingapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wdpr.ee</groupId>
            <artifactId>wdpr-ra-java-mpropzapi</artifactId>
            <version>${mpropz.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wdpr.ee</groupId>
            <artifactId>wdpr-authz</artifactId>
            <version>${authz.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>${easymock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wdat.ttt</groupId>
            <artifactId>ttt-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wdat.ttt</groupId>
            <artifactId>ttt-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <ignores>
                            <ignore>com.wdat.ttt.rest.api.config</ignore>
                        </ignores>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/wdat/ttt/Application.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/wdat/ttt/rest/api/controller/impl/SwaggerControllerImpl.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/wdat/ttt/rest/api/config/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check>
                        <branchRate>${cobertura.percentage}</branchRate>
                        <lineRate>${cobertura.percentage}</lineRate>
                        <totalBranchRate>${cobertura.percentage}</totalBranchRate>
                        <totalLineRate>${cobertura.percentage}</totalLineRate>
                        <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                    </check>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please suggest. This is working fine in my local environment.

*Full Agent Registration Info Resolver using node name [b196dc6a-64de-469b-b70d-78e99a12b504]
Install Directory resolved to[/opt/appdynamics]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.*

Comment: does this help with your issue?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572783/no-log4j2-configuration-file-found-using-default-configuration-logging-only-er

Comment: No actually in local tit is working but it is not working in latest

Comment: as this produces a .war file, by any chance you have local files in your lib/conf folder in your server that you don't on the external env?