# How to set threshold for console appender in log4j?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, catalina

I need DEBUG in one file and INFO in a the catalina.out. here is my log4j properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=  consoleAppenderInfo, fileAppenderInfo, fileAppenderDebug

log4j.appender.consoleAppenderInfo.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.consoleAppenderInfo=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppenderInfo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppenderInfo.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.fileAppenderInfo.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.fileAppenderInfo=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppenderInfo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppenderInfo.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppenderInfo.File=/home/user/logs/info.app.log

log4j.appender.fileAppenderDebug.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.fileAppenderDebug=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppenderDebug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppenderDebug.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppenderDebug.File=/home/user/logs/debug.app.log
```

while both output files get the correct log, catalina.out show this:

`2023-09-19 11:09:25,276 http-apr-8080-exec-35 WARN No Loggers were configured, using default. Is the Loggers element missing?`

it will go away if I set INFO on the root logger. however i cant have debug log with that.

Comment: Have you tried the sollutions provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572783/no-log4j2-configuration-file-found-using-default-configuration-logging-only-er

Comment: no it either didn't work not applicable towards what I'm trying to do